# Java Data Structure Array List vs Linked List

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a list of randomly generated numbers and want to store them in a structure, then remove them from the structure in the order they were generated.

So, I need a data structure with best remove first.

Both Linked List and Array List has remove of O(1)

Is one better than the other? If so, in what ways?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist

Comment: It sounds like you need a queue. Overall this can be easily found out with Google. -1

Comment: yeah but those are fore general remove (i.e. cases in the middle). For me, I am only dealing with cases of remove first, O(1) for both which mean it does not matter which one I use. But I was wondering if my thought process is correct

Comment: Yes. Queue is exactly what I thought of. But I am forbidden to use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java, the `LinkedList` class implements the `Queue` interface.  Which means it works as a queue.  If you use `.add()` you will put things at the end of the list (queue), and if you use `.remove()`, you will pull things from the head of the list (queue).

Retrieval from an `ArrayList` is O(1), but removal is not.  Consider the following:

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
al.add(1);
al.add(2);
al.add(3);
```

Your list `al` is now `{1, 2, 3}`.

Now you do: `al.remove(0)`

After that, `al` is `{2, 3}`.  But for this to happen, once you removed the head of the list, all other objects *after* the head needed to shift down one unit.  So it was actually O(n).  Removal is only O(1) if you are removing the tail.  But you need to be removing the head each time.

Comment: Array List automatically shifts the elements down? So, if i do al.remove(0) twice. it will get rid of 1 and then 2? i thought the index 0 will just be null after the first removal?

Comment: @ealeon Think about what would happen if it didn't.  Your list would become fragmented when you removed elements from the middle.  If your list was fragmented, how could you have random access?  How would you know the distance from `al[0]` to `al[324]` if there were gaps all throughout the array?  The defining characteristic of arrays (and ArrayLists) is contiguity.

Comment: @ealeon Please consider accepting the answer if it helped you understand. :-)  Thanks.